# How can I put a value to the right of a chemical equation?

Tags: equations, chemistry

I am trying to figure out how to put a value (e.g. ∆H>0 or E_cell=1.10 V) to the right  of a chemical equation.
For example

```
\ce{Cu ^{2+}(aq) + Zn(s) -> Cu(s) + Zn^{2+} (aq) E_{cell}^\standardstate = \SI{1.10}{\volt}}
```

However the value is jammed up against the equation and using `\verbatim{   }` seems a bit crude. 
Thanks,

Cam

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please consider posting not just a code snippet but something that's compilable. For starters, do indicate which packages define the macros `\ce`, `\standardstate`, and `\SI`.

Comment: Did you try adding, say `\quad` first?

Answer (score 4):

Since TeX ignores spaces in math formulas, you need to add an explicit one, typically `\quad` or `\qquad`.

Note: in the code I removed `\standardstate` as I don't know its definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\[
\ce{Cu^{2+}(aq) + Zn(s) -> Cu(s) + Zn^{2+} (aq)}
\qquad E_{\mathrm{cell}}^{0} = \SI{1.10}{\volt}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `Cu ^{2+}(aq)` should rather be `Cu^{2+}(aq)`.

Comment: @mhchem I supposed the OP had reasons for the space! :)